# Why does GCC not complain about _Bool in c89 mode?

Tags: gcc, c89

Why does the following command produce no warnings or errors, even though `_Bool` is not part of C89?

```
  $ echo "_Bool x;" | gcc -x c -c -std=c89 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -
```

For comparison, changing `_Bool` to `bool` results in an error:

```
  $ echo "bool x;" | gcc -x c -c -std=c89 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -
  <stdin>:1:6: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘x’
```

This happens on Cygwin [gcc (GCC) 4.5.3] and Linux [gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)].

Comment: Even in C99, `bool` doesn't exist without `#include <stdbool.h>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `_Bool` in a C89 compiler invokes *undefined behavior* because you use an identifier starting with an underscore and upper case letter. I don't have the paper copy of C89 handy, but expect it to be the same as C99 7.1.3:

> — All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an
>   uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any
>   use.

One permissible undefined behavior is accepting `_Bool` without a diagnostic. This is a GNU extension.

Of course, `bool` doesn't fall into the implementation namespace, so must be diagnosed unless declared.

Comment: So GCC emits no warning when undefined behaviour is invoked?

Comment: Correction: It emits a warning when _Complex is used in c89 mode, but not _Bool.  Seems rather arbitrary.

Comment: Detecting undefined behavior for the general case is impossible (it needs solving the halting problem). For particular cases it might be feasible, which is why the C Standard wisely left it open. Undefined is undefined is undefined. Anything can happen. A diagnostic is anything. Being silent is anything, too.

Comment: Sure, but this is a very specific case, which seems to be arbitrarily handled one way for _Complex and another way for _Bool.

Comment: You can always lobby the GCC maintainers to change it for "consistency with _Complex". But it's not a strong argument for a *I like it more like that* issue :-)